# How to prevent HTML documentation files in NuGet package from being copied to content folder

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

I'm building a NuGet package using the online "NuGet Packager" template in Visual Studio 2013. I've got the following file structure in my project:

```
content/
docs/
  |
  +- Install.md
  |
  +- Install.html
lib/
src/
tools/
```

As a point of reference, I have the Web Essentials extension for Visual Studio installed, and the `docs/Install.md` file is compiled from Markdown to HTML upon save.

With the default `Package.nuspec` settings for including files, the `docs` directory is being copied to the .nupkg file's `content` directory.

The `<files>` section of Package.nuspec:

```xml
<files>
  <file src="lib\" target="lib" />
  <file src="tools\" target="tools" />
  <file src="docs\*" target="lib\docs" exclude="docs\**\*.md" />
  <file src="content\" target="content" />
</files>
```

The resulting file structure of the .nupkg file:

```
content/
    docs/
        Install.html <-- This is NOT correct
lib/
    docs/
        Install.html <-- This is correct
package/
tools/
```

Some additional variation of my `<files>` specification that didn't work:

```xml
<file src="content\" target="content" exclude="docs" />
<file src="content\" target="content" exclude="docs\*" />
<file src="content\" target="content" exclude="docs\**\*" />
<file src="content\" target="content" exclude="content\docs" />
<file src="content\" target="content" exclude="content\docs\" />
<file src="content\" target="content" exclude="content\docs\*" />
<file src="content\" target="content" exclude="content\docs\**\*" />
```

If I exclude the `docs` folder my my Visual Studio project this folder no longer shows up in the resulting `content` folder, and gets copied to the lib folder like I want, but this breaks the handy workflow of saving the .md file and having Web Essentials convert it to HTML on save.

**Why is my `lib/docs` folder being copied to the `content` folder in the .nupkg file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate it when I do this. 15 seconds after posting the question I discovered the answer.

Two things appear to be going on:

1. HTML files, by default, are given a "Build Action" in Visual Studio of "Content"
2. NuGet picks up on this and will toss any file with this Build Action --- in any directory in your project --- into the `content` folder of the .nupkg file.

**The Fix:**

1. Right-click on the HTML file
2. In the "Properties" pane, select "None" for the "Build Action"
3. Clean and build the project